# Flutter - Smooth transition color for LinearGradient

Tags: flutter

Hellow!

Is there a solution for creating a LinearGradient that has a smooth transition between start and ens color?

```
new Container(
        decoration: new BoxDecoration(
          gradient: new LinearGradient(
              colors: [
                Colors.black,
                Colors.grey,
              ],
            stops: [0.0, 1.0],
            begin: FractionalOffset.topCenter,
            end: FractionalOffset.bottomCenter,
            tileMode: TileMode.repeated
          )
        ),
)
```

[image: Image showing gradient with poor color resolution]

Comment: What's wrong here ?

Answer (score 18):

In your main function set `Paint.enableDithering = true;` just like below:

Don't forget to **restart** the app

```
void main() {
  Paint.enableDithering = true;
  runApp(DesignChallenge05());
}
```

Comment: This made no difference for me

Comment: It worked for me. Make sure to restart and not hot reload.

Comment: Paint.enableDithering = true now by default in Flutter apps

Answer (score 10):

It appears as though that may be from the Android Emulator. If that is the case, it uses a low-quality renderer so that it runs fast enough especially on less powerful hardware. Test it out on a real device and you'll likely see better results. I believe you may also be able to bump up the graphics on the emulator but not 100% sure if that would improve this. See [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-acceleration.html).

This is what the gradient looks like on a Nexus 4 vs the emulator.

[image: Emulator vs Device]

Comment: I obtained better results testing on a real device. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

You can try with this Linear Gradient

```
new Container(
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
          gradient: LinearGradient(begin: Alignment.bottomRight, stops: [
            0.1,
            0.9
          ], colors: [
            Colors.black.withOpacity(.8),
            Colors.black.withOpacity(.1)
          ])),
    ),
```

Answer (score 1):

When you transition between similar colors over a large distance (hundreds of pixels), a screen may not be able to render it smoothly.

A possible solution is to create a background image with the gradient in Photoshop. After you are happy with the image, cut it to 1 px width, and use it as a background image, repeating vertically.

Comment: Even with this approach I got the same results.Thanks!

Comment: If the screen is unable to display certain colors it doesnt matter if the colors come from an image or not

Comment: Most screens these days are very good at displaying all colors. The difference is that Photoshop, historically, had a better algorithm for calculating colors for a smooth visual gradient. This may not be true anymore as browsers, mobile and other rendering engines are more and more powerful.

Answer (score 0):

If you already tried `Paint.enableDithering = true;` and it still didnt work:

- Check if you are using colors with transparency. I noticed that by using colors with opacity < 100%, it causes this error.

If you are, change the opacity to **100**%, `(R, G, B, 1)`.